# How do we define log-normal prior and a multivariate posterior log-likelihood in PyMC?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, computational-statistics, hierarchical-bayesian, pymc

I am a newbie with pyMC and I am not still able to construct the structure of my MCMC with pyMC. I would like to establish a chain and I am confused how to define my parameters and log-likelihood function together. My chi-squared function is given by:

[image]

where [image] and [image] are observational data and correspondence error respectively and [image] is the model with four free parameter and the parameters are non-linear.

The priors for `X` and `Y` are uniform but for `M` and `C` are given as following:

[image] ;

where the probability of `c` follows log-normal distribution while the expectation value of `c` is computed with the above formula and is the function of `M` and $\sigma$ is `0.09` if $M < 10^{15}$ otherwise $\sigma=0.06$:

[image]

[image]

for each `C` the parameter `z` is constant. I am wondering how I could define my likelihood for [image] , and should it be referred as @Deterministic variable? Did I define `M` and `C` as priori information in a correct way or not?
I will be grateful if somebody gives me some tips that how I can combine these parameters with given priors.

```
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np
import math
import random
from scipy.stats import expon

@pm.stochastic(dtype=np.float, observed=False, trace=True)
def Xpos(value=1900,x_l=1800,x_h=1950):
    """The probable region of the position of halo centre"""
    def logp(value,x_l,x_h):
        if ((value>x_h) or (value<x_l)):
       return -np.inf
    else:
       return -np.log(x_h-x_l+1)
    def random(x_l,x_h):
        return np.round((x_h-x_l)*random.random())+x_l

@pm.stochastic(dtype=np.float, observed=False, trace=True)
def Ypos(value=1750,y_l=1200,y_h=2000):
    """The probable region of the position of halo centre"""
    def logp(value,y_l,y_h):
        if ((value>y_h) or (value<y_l)):
       return -np.inf
    else:
       return -np.log(y_h-y_l+1)
    def random(y_l,y_h):
        return np.round((y_h-y_l)*random.random())+y_l


M=math.pow(10,15)*pm.Exponential('mass', beta=math.pow(10,15))

@pm.stochastic(dtype=np.float, observed=False, trace=True)
def concentration(value=4, zh, M200): #c parameter
    """logp for concentration parameter"""
    def logp(value=4.,zh, M):
        if (value>0):
       x = np.linspace(math.pow(10,13),math.pow(10,16),200 )
       prob=expon.pdf(x,loc=0,scale=math.pow(10,15))
       conc = [5.26/(1.+zh)*math.pow(x[i]/math.pow(10,14),-0.1) for i in range(len(x))]
       mu_c=0
       for i in range(len(x)):
           mu_c+=prob[i]*conc[i]/sum(prob)
       if (M < pow(10,15)):
          tau=1./(0.09*0.09)
       else:
          tau=1./(0.06*0.06)
           return  pm.lognormal_like(value, mu_c, tau)
        else
           return -np.inf
    def random(mu_c,tau):
        return np.random.lognormal(mu_c, tau, 1)
```

Comment: Is this a self-study question?

Comment: Well @Matthew I am learning by myself how to use pyMC to code my problem. I am trying to define my variables correctly before starting any MCMC chain.

Comment: $X, Y, M, C$ all have probability distributions, so they would be @Stochastic class. All you said about $\hat g$ is that it is a 'model', can you write out what that means exactly? Does $\hat g$ have random components? It seems that you have defined the prior of $C, M$ already?

Comment: @Matthew $\hat{g}$ is a non-linear function of $(X,Y,M,C)$. I assume I can define a uniform prior for $X,Y$, since I have prior knowledge where they are roughly located and it might prevent of degeneracy between the results if I run MCMC with different initial conditions. I also think **Jeffreys prior** can describe $M$ very well but I do not know how to define $M,C$ priors and I appreciate if you can help.

Comment: @Matthew I modify my question by adding what I have written so far and add some more details. I would like that somebody with the experience coding with `pymc` take a look and confirm I have coded my problem in the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your @stochastic uses are not correct. Notice that your functions don't return anything. When using the decorator, you're supposed to return value of the logp. See [here](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelbuilding.html?highlight=decorator#creation-of-stochastic-variables) for example usage.

If you're going to use @stochastic I think you probably want something like this for each of your @stochastic uses.

```
@pm.stochastic(dtype=np.float, observed=False, trace=True)
def Xpos(value=1900,x_l=1800,x_h=1950):
    """The probable region of the position of halo centre"""

    if ((value>x_h) or (value<x_l)):
       return -np.inf
    else:
       return -np.log(x_h-x_l+1)
```

(directly returning the logp)

If you need to provide a random() function (I suspect you don't), I think you can pass it to stochastic.

However, since you just want a uniform prior for Xpos and Ypos, you can just use `Uniform` instead.

```
Xpos = Uniform("Xpos", 1800, 1950)
```

Your concentration stochastic seems very complicated given that C is pretty straightforward. I would expect it to directly follow your definition of C.

g_hat should definitely be a @deterministic, since you say its a function. If so, it shouldn't have a likelihood of its own.

For concentration, you want something like

```
@deterministic
def sigma(value = 1, M=M): 
   if M > 10**15:
       return .09
   else:
       return .06

cExpected = const/(1+z)*M**-.1
concentration = Lognormal("concentration", cExpected, sigma)
```

Comment: I add more description to the problem. For `x` and `y`, I was following the pyMC manual and I thought if I want to instantiate Stochastic directly I need to also generate the random data for MCMC sampling later. On the other hand my main concern is how to define prior for `c`.

Comment: Where were you looking in the manual? Perhaps that section can be improved. I've updated the answer.

Comment: The example for Decorator Stochastic class section 4.2 for parameter `s` in 'PyMC:Bayesian Stochastic Modelling in Python'. I was wondering why the function `random` is defined, e.g. because in sampling parameter space MCMC needs to generate random steps and then test for the acceptance rate or not?

Comment: if we go back to my problem, M parameter has an exponential distribution, then when I define `cExpected` which is the `Expected value of c` with a given functionality of `M`  and its distribution, shouldn't I compute the expectation value with considering the exponential distribution of M and insert it in the concentration formula? What is the role of `random()` function in `decorator` shape of **Stochastic** class?

Comment: No. M does not neccessarily have an exponential distribution, only an exponential prior distribution. I think I see what you're asking, whether you have to correct for the first parameter being the location parameter and not the expectation, and yes you do (http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/distributions.html#pymc.distributions.lognormal_like). I don't think you need random, don't worry about it. Or look it up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My problem is very complicated, I have a class that one of its method is the function $\hat{g}$, while it($\hat{g}$) has an extra parameter, lets say `z` and I want to marginalize over it before using it for **MCMC** sampling, since the $p(z)$ is a discrete probability distribution and its amount is given via a file. Can I post more for extra help?

Comment: Definitely! I don't have much more time to devote to this, but I'm sure you can find others to help.